# Jquery on Hover Bounc and Ease

Tags: jquery, animation, easing

I am a newbie to j Query and i have this website that i built along time ago with flash. Now i want to make the same effect but with j Query. Please see the effect on the below URL.

http://theark.co.ke/

I have tried some thing see the code below but something is just not right, it is not smooth and every time i hover on any of the circles i get an error on the console of firebug. Please advice mates, thanks

```
 <div class="circle floatleft" id="circle1"><p>Circle One</p></div>
 <div class="circle floatleft" id="circle2"><p>Circle two</p></div>
 <div class="circle floatleft" id="circle3"><p>Circle three</p></div>
 <div class="circle floatleft" id="circle4"><p>Circle four</p></div>
```

I have some simple CSS for demo purposes

```
.circle{border-radius: 50%;border: 5px solid #FFBD00;background:#4679BD;color:#fff;text-align:center;margin:auto;vertical-align:middle;padding:20px;min-width:100px;min-height:100px;}
```

.floatleft{float:left;}
.circle > p{vertical-align:middle;margin:auto;text-align:center;}

And the jquery that i am experimenting with

```
$(".circle").hover(function() {
        //resize other circles
        var circleHeight = $(".circle").height();
        var circleWidth = $(".circle").width();
        $(".circle").animate({'opacity' : '0.5', 'height' : circleHeight / 4, 'width' : circleWidth / 4});
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
                'height': $this.height() * 1.2,
                'width' : $this.width() * 1.2,
                'opacity' : '1'
            });
        },function() {
               $(".circle").animate({'opacity' : '1', 'height' : circleHeight * 4, 'width' : circleWidth * 4});
               var $this = $(this);
               $this.animate({
                'height': $this.height() / 1.2,
                'width' : $this.width() / 1.2
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to differ between `$this.height()` and `circleWidth` because in your function, they are the same elements.

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu8Y9/2/). I bet you can optimize the code further, this is just a modification to makt it work without throwing errors.

```
$(".circle").hover(function() {
    //resize other circles
    var element = $(this);
    var circleHeight = element.height();
    var circleWidth = element.width();
    element.animate({'opacity' : '0.5', 'height' : circleHeight / 4, 'width' : circleWidth / 4});
    element.animate({
        'height': circleHeight * 1.2,
        'width' : circleWidth * 1.2,
        'opacity' : '1'
    });
},function(circleHeight, circleWidth) {
    var element = $(this);
    element.animate({'opacity' : '1', 'height' : circleHeight * 4, 'width' : circleWidth * 4});
    element.animate({
        'height': circleHeight / 1.2,
        'width' : circleWidth / 1.2
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not bulletproof yet (if you mouse-out and over again, it will freak out) but you may looking for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var originalHeight, originalWidth;

    $(".circle").css('opacity','0.5');
    $(".circle").hover(function () {
        var object = $(this);
        originalHeight = object.height();
        originalWidth = object.width();

        $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1', 'height': originalHeight * 4, 'width': originalWidth * 4 },
        { duration: 1200, easing: 'easeOutElastic' });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0.5', 'height': originalHeight, 'width': originalWidth },
        { duration: 1200, easing: 'easeOutElastic' });
    });
});
```

Don't forget to include the [jquery.easing.min.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js). This way the easing will be a lot smoother. You can find [all of the easingtypes here](http://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html)